# Convert Javascript Object to String (Literal Source Code Version)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that allows users to construct a javascript object that is later used as a settings object for their HTML pages. Once they construct the object, they need to **copy and paste** the object onto their websites.

The object *is* mutli-dimensional.

I do not want to use something like `JSON.stringify` because it's not trusted cross-browser. Also, `JSON.stringify` gives you the JSON encoded version but I am trying to get a literal source-code version.

I am willing to send the object to a PHP script via ajax if that will help, so a PHP solution works as well.

Once again, just in case I'm not making sense...

If I have a javascript variable:

```
var object={
configs:{
    widgetLink:{
        publisherID:12,
        enabled:true,
        'background-color':'green'
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need a text-area to display **the same thing as the source code**:

```
<textarea id="output">var object={
configs:{
    widgetLink:{
        publisherID:12,
        enabled:true,
        'background-color':'green'
        }
    }
}
</textrea>
```

The object will be created and edited dynamically so somehow I have to use jQuery to do it. `$('#output').text(objectToSourceCode(object));`

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll probably need to construct a representation of the object by looping over it and building up the 'source code' view.

Comment: Consider using a `<pre>` tag instead of `<textarea>` to preserve whitespace and to inherit super awesome monospaced font.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` isn't trusted cross browser???

Comment: Thanks rick, good idea. And no, JSON.stringify does not support IE7 or circular references.

Comment: That's far different from not being "trusted". For browsers where it isn't *supported*, you'd use a shim.

Comment: How are you going to manage a circular reference in a copy/paste (source code) situation?

Comment: Why not to use proven and stable WYSIWYG editors, like `TinyMCE 4`??! That work "cross-browserly"

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify then use regex to remove the extra quotes